# buffer to file stream

Tags: node.js, upload, box, multer

I would like to create file uploading app to box storage. I use box-sdk module to upload box. The box-sdk can access a file stream that is came from fs.createReadStream for uploading. I use multer module to access uploaded file. The multer module has memorystorage to store files. It produces a buffer string.

For uploading box, I have to convert buffer string to file stream. How can I convert it?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a readable-stream and push your buffer into it.

```
var stream = require('stream')
var bufStream = stream.Readable()
bufStream._read = function () {}
bufStream.push(myBuffer)
bufStream.push(null)
bufStream.pause()
```

You can then `pipe` `bufStream` wherever you need to pipe it.

You can also use [several](https://github.com/rvagg/node-simple-bufferstream), [various](https://github.com/gagle/Node-Streamifier) modules to handle this for you